# How to assign uncertainty to belonging to different populations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics

I have three Numpy arrays.

The first is the sum of all values:

```
 population_total = np.array([[0, 3, 5, 7], 
                              [6, 2, 4, 2],
                              [9, 7, 2, 0], 
                              [0, 2, 1, 0]]
```

The second and third are my known population parameters. They do not equal the total population count because not all populations are known.

```
 population_one = np.array([[0, 2, 3, 5], 
                            [1, 2, 3, 2],
                            [0, 1, 2, 0], 
                            [0, 0, 0, 0]]

 population_two = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0], 
                            [4, 0, 1, 0],
                            [7, 4, 0, 0], 
                            [0, 1, 1, 0]]
```

I wanted to assign each point a probability of belonging to either population one or population two so I can classify the uncertain points.

I want to say something like this for each point: There is a 70% chance that this point belongs to population 1 and 20% chance that it belongs to population 2.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you mean with "if you add everything up, you get 1"?

Comment: What would be the expected output for the given data?

Comment: I wanted two arrays with the chance that the member of the total population belongs to either population one or two.

Answer (score 1):

The chance of belonging to the first population is just the elementwise division of the `population_one` matrix over the `population_total`. Perhaps it is worth first explicitly converting total populations with sum `0` to `NaN`, since in that case the idea of probability does not exists:

```
pop_tot = population_total.astype(float)
pop_tot[pop_tot == 0] = np.nan
```

Then the probabilities for one, two and three are respectively:

```
>>> population_one/pop_tot
array([[       nan, 0.66666667, 0.6       , 0.71428571],
       [0.16666667, 1.        , 0.75      , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 0.14285714, 1.        ,        nan],
       [       nan, 0.        , 0.        ,        nan]])
>>> population_two/pop_tot
array([[       nan, 0.33333333, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.66666667, 0.        , 0.25      , 0.        ],
       [0.77777778, 0.57142857, 0.        ,        nan],
       [       nan, 0.5       , 1.        ,        nan]])
>>> (population_total-population_one-population_two)/pop_tot
array([[       nan, 0.        , 0.4       , 0.28571429],
       [0.16666667, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.22222222, 0.28571429, 0.        ,        nan],
       [       nan, 0.5       , 0.        ,        nan]])
```

In case of a `nan`, the probability does not make much sense. If a total population has 0 items, then how can you say "It is …% likely to be from group *i*"?